# PowerShell - Show output / action on screen

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Have this script

```
"`n" 
$user = Read-Host "Enter Username"
write-Host "Finding" -ForegroundColor Red
$filePath = "\\myserver\d$\location\$user\Profile\AppData\Roaming\app\$user" 
"`n" 

$Response = Read-Host "Do you want to delete the contents of this directory for '$user' ?(Y/N)"
if($Response -eq "Y"){
   get-childitem $filepath -recurse | foreach ($_) {remove-item $_.fullname}
 }else{
    Write-Host "No such user found or directory does not exist..."
}

write-Host "" 
write-Host "------------Process Complete Files Removed--------------------" -ForegroundColor magenta


Start-Sleep -s 120
```

I would love to show the output of the files being deleted / the process actually taking place. Any way of doing this before the process complete part of the script?

Comment: Use Write-Progress inside your ForEach-Object loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `-Verbose` parameter on `Remove-Item`:

```
Get-ChildItem $filepath -recurse | Where {!$_.PSIsContainer} | Remove-Item -verbose
```